# Subversion: download files modified between 2 revisions

Tags: svn, open-source, diff, trac

We are currently using trac and have become dependent on one of its features.
Within the source browser, you can press View Changes and see all the diffs between 2 revisions. And we love being able to download a zip file that contains all the files modified, in their directory structure.

Is there another open-source application that can do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very easy to get the same result using just commandline `svn`. You could write a script that will get those values for you if your new trac-replacement won't have that feature. Here's the demo script in bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
// replace 100 and 120 with revision numbers
svn diff -r 100:120 "svn://path.to.your.svn.repo" > svn.rev.diff
gzip svn.rev.diff
```

This will give you a nice gzipped diff file (`svn.rev.diff.gz`) between two revisions. Of course you could add some params to it instead of hardcoding the numbers but that's just to show how this can be done.

Comment: i dont need the diff file but the file itself ... since i usually use it to upload them by SFTP

Answer (score 2):

get_file.sh with this content would work

```
echo "++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
echo "usage ./get_file.sh 13910 13914"
echo "++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"

REPO=http://svn.urcompany.com/urproduct/trunk
for i in $(svn diff --summarize -r $1:$2 $REPO | awk '{ print $2 }'); do p=$(echo $i | sed -e "s{$REPO/{{"); mkdir -p $(dirname $p); echo $i; svn export --force $i $p; done
```

Thanks to http://www.clearintent.co.uk/subversion/technical/support/output_a_list_of_changes_between_2_revisions/699